# Create a list of duplicate records that are in several columns

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have a data set that is spread across five columns. Sample of data:

```
Raw Data                  End Results
A   B   C   D   E       A   B   C   D   E       
1   2   2   1   6       1   2   2   1   6
0   3   3   0   6       0   3   3   0   6
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6 
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6       
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6       
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6       
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6       
1   2   2   1   6       
0   3   3   0   6
```

The length of record varies from 10 to 40.

The data is to help me keep record of inventory and I wish to know which orders are popular.

Unfortunately I am still using Excel 2003.

Comment: So you need the number of orders for every order (A, B, C, D, E)?

Comment: Specify more exactly what you need.  What you have posted as raw data are two sets 1,2,2,1,6 and 0,3,3,0,6 that alternate - what's your real data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Because I am not really sure what you have, this is deliberately simple:

In ColumnG Row1 put:

```
=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1
```

and copy down to suit. Select ColumnG and Paste Special, Values. Select ColumnG and sort. Insert in H1 and copy down to suit:

```
=COUNTIF(G$1:G1,G1)
```

`1` should indicate the first ("unique") instance of each of the rows of Raw Data (and the other numbers the number of repetitions - up to `7` in your example, so one 'original' and six 'copies'.